# Why or when should I use state within a custom Hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-custom-hooks

I am learning about custom Hooks in React. I have taken the following typical example (`useFetch`) as you can see in https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_customhooks.asp.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const useFetch = (url) => {
const [data, setData] = useState(null); /* <--- Why use this? */
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => setData(data));
  }, [url]);
  return [data];
};
export default useFetch;
```

I'm confused why state should be used inside that Hook, or in general in custom Hooks. I always relate state management to components, not to a hook. Hence perhaps my confusion.

Couldn't it have been done simply by returning a data variable?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't see where the document clarifies precisely what I'm asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike normal functions, custom hooks encapsulates React state. This means that the hook can utilize react's own hooks and perform custom logic. It's quite abstract in that sense.

For your case, you want to return the *state* of the data, not just the *data* by itself because the state is tied to a `useEffect`. That means that `fetch` will only run and by extension only update `data` when its dependencies (`[url]`) are changed.

If it was a normal function just returning the data from the fetch, you would send a request every time the component using the hook re-renders. That's why you use `useState` coupled with `useEffect` to make sure it only updates when it should.